# Reshaping 1d array to 2D pointer array Fortran

Tags: pointers, fortran, intel-fortran

I have a pointer `uvw(:,:)` which is two-dimensional, and I got a 1d buffer array `x(:)`.

Now I need to point `uvw(1,:)=>x(1:ncell)`  and `uvw(2,:)=>x(ncell+1:ncell*2)` etc.

I made a very simple example. I know that array of pointers does not work, but does anybody have an idea how this can be worked around?

PS: For a pragmatic reason I do not want to wrap my uvw with a declared type. ( i am changing some bit of code, and need uvw as 2D pointer. Currently is an array, and my idea is to avoid changing the way uvw is being used as it being used thousands of times)

```
 program test

 real, allocatable,target :: x(:)
 real, pointer :: ptr(:,:)


allocate(x(100) )


x = 1.

ptr(1,:) => x(1:10)

end program
```

The error message says:

> `error #8524: The syntax of this data pointer assignment is incorrect:
>   either 'bound spec' or 'bound remapping' is expected in this context. 
>   [1]
>
> ptr(1,:) => x(1:10)
>
> ----^`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to perform *pointer bounds remapping*, but you have the incorrect syntax and approach.

Pointer bounds remapping is a way to have the shape of the pointer different from that of the target.  In particular, the rank of the pointer and target may differ.  However, in such an assignment it is necessary to explicitly specify the lower and upper bounds of the remapping; it isn't sufficient to use `:` by itself.

Also, you'll need to assign the whole pointer in one go.  That is, you can't have "the first ten elements point to this slice, the next ten to this slice" and so on in multiple statements.

The assignment statement would be

```
ptr(1:10,1:10) => x
```

Note, that this also means that you can't actually have what you want.  You are asking for the elements `ptr(1,1:10)` to correspond to `x(1:10)` and `ptr(2,2:10)` to correspond to `x(11:20)`.  That isn't possible: the array elements must match in order: `ptr(1:10,1)` being the first ten elements of `ptr` must instead be associated with the first ten elements `x(1:10)`.  The corrected pointer assignment above has this.

Comment: So you are saying this is impossible to do what I wanted? Is there any alternative thing to do.

Comment: Well, you can use `ptr(1:10,1:10) => x` and then use the transpose of `ptr` instead of `ptr` when referencing.  However, you indeed won't be able to have `ptr`'s elements point to elements of `x` out of order.  But if wanting the array elements of `ptr` not in the same order as those of `x` is just a typo, then you're quite fine to use this.  Further, if you don't really need the pointer nature, then `reshape` is plausible (see related questions).

Answer (score -1):

If you prefer avoiding a pointer, then the UNION/MAP is an option depending on compiler. It was added to gfortran a while ago... then you can think of the array as a rank=2 but also use the vector (Rank=1) for SIMD operations.

All this assumes that one wants to avoid pointers...

Comment: Health Warning: Union and Map are non-standard and their use may lead to code that is impossible to port to other platforms.