# how to view part of a one dimensional array as two dimensional without creating a new array

Tags: fortran

I have an array named 'storage' of 9 integer*4 elements. The following program splits storage into one-dimensional subarrays x (the first 3 elements of storage) and y (the remaining 6 elements), and prints the 3 elements of x, and then the 6 elements of y. Excellent! But I would like y to be two-dimensional, so I could reference the 6 elements of y as y(1,1),...,y(2,3) (either column- or row-major order, does not matter). How to do it?

```
      integer*4 storage(*),x(*),y(*)
      pointer(pst,storage)
      pointer(px,x)
      pointer(py,y)
      integer*4 SIZE,I
      SIZE=4
      pst=malloc(SIZE*9)
      if(pst == 0) then
      print *,'FAILED!'
      stop
      else
      px=pst
      py=pst+SIZE*3
      do 10 I=1,9
10    storage(I)=10*I
      do 20 I=1,3
20    print*,'x(',I,')=',x(I)
      do 30 I=1,6
30    print*,'y(',I,')=',y(I)
      endif
      end
```

I am not a Fortran expert. I see such commands as 'reshape', etc. But I do not want to create a new array! (Because storage in real life will be GB size, I cannot duplicate it.) Just how to reference those 6 elements as a 2 x 3 array: read them or assign new values to them?

I have
@ uname -a
HP-UX rx2800 B.11.31 U ia64

I have tried to compile the solution given in the duplicate by janneb, but I get:

Error 805 at (7:k.f) : This pointer and the target must have the same type, type parameters and rank

I also tried the solution by Lance Larsen, but I get:

function getArray(array, shape_) result(aptr)
^
Error 1094 at (27:h.f) : syntax error - misplaced statement

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Always read the descriptions of tags you are adding. Proper tags are very important here. Use tag [tag:fortran] for Fortran questions. Use indentation to make your code clearer to understand and avoid DO with numeric labels. Use END DO instead.

Comment: Definitely avoid the integer pointers (also called Cray pointers). They are not standard Fortran at all and modern Fortran has much better resources instead.

Comment: Also be aware that reshape often does not  need to create any new storage. It depends on what exactly you do with it. Modern Fortran has pointer remapping described in several questions and answers on this site.

Comment: As you are already (shudder) using Cray pointers, you can use _proper_ pointers and point a rank-two pointer at the rank-one target, such as shown in answer to the linked question. Or pass `y` to a second procedure associating it with an argument of desired shape. (Or, with even more shuddering, use equivalence.)

Comment: The solution is "pointer bound remapping". See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57059686/14778592

Comment: `integer, pointer :: y2(:,:)`, then `y2(1:2,1:3) => y(:)`

Comment: It is hard to tell what exactly you did when you got the new errors. The answers do work when applied properly, that means in the right context.